# $\epsilon$- net theorems

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, computational-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Here we are going to consider problems of the following type:

We have a family set F of satisfying certain conditions, 
meaning that we can choose a bounded number of points such that each set of F contains at least one of them.

[image]

Technically,  $\epsilon$-nets have widely application among  mathematics and computer science.
for more information see below links ;

https://scholar.google.nl/scholar?q=epsilon+nets+and+Its+application&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA_cfTt53OAhVImBoKHU1JDlQQgQMIGjAA

https://scs.carleton.ca/content/vc-dimension-and-epsilon-nets-applications-visibility-problems

Weather you are famillier with prelimenary defination or not I provided some references here:

Chapter 10: LECTURES ON DISCRETE GEOMETRY (Jiri Matousek)
 http://www.ti.inf.ethz.ch/ew/lehre/CG12/lecture/Chapter%2015.pdf
http://sarielhp.org/teach/08/a/lec/24_vcdim.pdf
https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/VcDimension.pdf

The Basic is simple for who is interested in combinatorics problem...
But difficulties come to you from initiate

***Some one tell me what is the general definition $\epsilon$-  net theorems ???***
I've found 3 difference version of them :

**First**

Chapter 10: LECTURES ON DISCRETE GEOMETRY (Jiri Matousek)

> [image]

**Second**

http://sarielhp.org/teach/08/a/lec/24_vcdim.pdf

> [image]

**Third**

https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/VcDimension.pdf

> [image]

I want categorize them in order to use in my Bachelor Project So even intoducing a new reference or new application or a new combinatorial approach will help me alot...